# Referancing models that is in another CakePhp project

Tags: cakephp, model-view-controller, cakephp-2.0

I have two different CakePhp projects that are connected to the same database. One of the projects is the web front end and other is for REST Api.

The common thing about these projects are mostly the models. If I want to introduce a table to the database, I need to write the same models in both projects.

I'm looking for a way to reference a model that is in another project. Maybe I can create a shared CakePhp project and just put models in it and then reference these models in our own projects.

By this way we can version separately our models from our web and api projects.

Comment: Why doesn't your front end just query your API? just remove all back end from one project and replace it with API calls to your other project? Release an interface and you're done

Comment: it will be too much work for now, I need to change all the views. I'm planning but not in near future.

Comment: The other way to go is add all your projects all under the same cakephp skeleton so you have one model structure and then a different controller-view structure but that would get really confusing if let's say you have two models that reference the same table but have different behaviour. I don't recommend it.